# Merge rows into one row - SQL 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Well, I have a table like this:

```
     ID DATETIME             FK_FEDERAL_STATE     FK_ACCOMODATION   ARRIVALS     NIGHTS
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------- ---------- ----------
    123185 200010               W96-5                             61       2433      16111
    123186 200010               W96-5                             86       3718      30319
    123187 200010               W96-5                             87       1100       8487
```

One hint: the Datetime = first 4 number = year + last 2 numbers = month

So far so good.

This is my SQL Statement:

```
SELECT DATETIME, SUM(NIGHTS) AS NIGHTS FROM dwh_data GROUP BY ROLLUP(DATETIME);
```

This gives me every DATETIME loooking like this:

```
DATETIME                 NIGHTS
-------------------- ----------
202008                 17994407
202009                  9895439
202010                  4347704
202011                  1075204
```

As you can see my SQL query shows the nights of each Month. Is it possible to sum up all nights from a year so f.e.

```
    DATETIME                 NIGHTS
    -------------------- ----------
    2018                 117994407
    2019                  19895439
    2020                  14347704
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to a date, and then group by year of that converted date:

```
GROUP BY YEAR(TO_DATE(DATETIME, 'YYYYMM'))
```

Or you could group by a substring which only looks at those first 4 characters:

```
GROUP BY SUBSTR(DATETIME, 1, 4)
```

Comment: How to implment in my query. I tried both of them and nothing of them work

Comment: What result are you getting? Are you seeing an error?

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear. See my edited question to see the result which I'd like to get

Comment: Your desired output doesn't make sense - you don't have any of those years in the table sample you provided. This answer will group your results by year, you just need to change the SELECT statement so you only see the year.

Comment: That was the question. Maybe you could edit your answer so I can approve your question

Comment: I gave you two ways of extracting the year from that column - just `SELECT SUBSTR(DATETIME, 1, 4), SUM(NIGHTS)`, or use the other method depending on your preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try GROUPING SETS to get both subtotals by YEAR and DATETIME.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(DATETIME, 1, 4) year, DATETIME, SUM(NIGHTS) AS NIGHTS 
FROM dwh_data 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((SUBSTR(DATETIME, 1, 4), DATETIME), (SUBSTR(DATETIME, 1, 4)) ) ;
```

Comment: First of all, see the result I woul like to get and see the result you get with your query. Furhtermore, you removed the ROLLUP which I would like to use in my query

Comment: You needn't ROLLUP to get the desired output in the question.  Just `GROUP BY SUBSTR(DATETIME, 1, 4)` as @Bashton suggested